# Creating dynamic names to inputs created by jquery append

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, input, keyup

I have a HTML like below:

```
NOF:
<input type="text" class="nof" />

<div class="myfld">
</div>
```

And the `jquery`:

```
html = '';
var html = 'Name : <input type="text" name="ss" />';
var html = html + 'Email : <input type="text" name="email" />';

$('.nof').keyup(function(){
$('.myfld').empty();
    nof = $('.nof').val();
    for(var x = 0;  x < nof; x++) {
        $('.myfld').append(html);
    }
});
```

When I key up, it's creating the input fields dynamically and upto this point working nicely. But the problem is all the fields created are having same name as `ss` and `email`. So how can I make these names as `ss1`,`email1`,`ss2`,`email2` and so on?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49gJG/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('.nof').keyup(function(){
$('.myfld').empty();
    nof = $('.nof').val();
    for(var x = 0;  x < nof; x++) {
        $('.myfld').append('Name : <input type="text" name="ss_'+x+'" />Email : <input type="text" name="email_'+x+'" /><br/>');
    }
});
```

everytime you append the inputs you also change the name of the inputs so for 3 inputs you have something like ss_0/email_0, ss_1/email_1, ss_3/email_3

Answer (score 0):

You can move the corresponding lines inside for loop

```
var html = ''; 
for (var x...) {
html = 'Name : <input type="text" name="ss' + x + '" />';
```

same for email

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a "Salt" at each iteration like this :

```
html = '';
var html = 'Name : <input type="text" name="ssFOO" />';
var html = html + 'Email : <input type="text" name="emailFOO" />';
var html = html + '<br />';

$('.nof').keyup(function(){
$('.myfld').empty();
    nof = $('.nof').val();
    for(var x = 0;  x < nof; x++) {
        var newHtml = html.replace(/FOO/g, String(x));
        $('.myfld').append(newHtml);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49gJG/8/)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this updated fiddle demo [http://jsfiddle.net/49gJG/7/]
 `Demo`